# Liferay 6.2 :How to populate values in 2nd Drop down based on 1st Dropdown in web content structure?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-aui

Can anyone help me How to Populate 2nd drop down based on first drop down in **Web Content Structure** in Liferay 6.2?

I have two Dropdown fields. 1) Countries 2) States

After selecting value in 1st Dropdown(Countries), 2nd dropdown (States) should be auto populated.

I am new to Liferay. Any suggestion will be helpful in this regard.

Best Regards,

Nagaraju

Comment: You can achieve this by creating portlet. Are you sure you want to do it in web content structure? You have to do ajax call on selection of countries which will fetch the values of states from the database. This can be done in portlet.

Comment: Hi Nisha Thanks for reply. Yes it can be done in Structure itself. Where i need to write ajax call? Shall i create custom jsp or in which jsp i need to modify? Could you please suggest me.   Thanks

Comment: I have worked on this kind of functionality, but we used portlet. If you know how to do it by web content structure, I would love to know that.